# Adding template suggestions for a view with display ID

Tags: views, theming, 9

I need to have suggestions for views to create dedicated template.
Actually I've this in my .theme:

```
function starter_d9_2022_theme_suggestions_views_view_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $suggestions[] = 'views_view__' . $variables['view']->id();
}
function starter_d9_2022_theme_suggestions_views_view_unformatted_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $suggestions[] = 'views_view_unformatted__' . $variables['view']->id();
}
function starter_d9_2022_theme_suggestions_views_view_list_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $suggestions[] = 'views_view_list__' . $variables['view']->id();
}
```

This provide:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x views-view--acces-rubriques-2019.html.twig
   x views-view--acces-rubriques-2019.html.twig
   x views-view--acces-rubriques-2019.html.twig
   * views-view.html.twig
-->
```

File is working,but code inside doesn't display views content. Anyway, I would to use a more specific template, by display like:

```
views-view--acces-rubriques-2019--list--block-1.html.twig
```

How can I add this to my actual code ?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple task. To achieve your desired template suggestion, you can add another suggestion that concatenates the display ID of the view. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
function starter_d9_2022_theme_suggestions_views_view_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $suggestions[] = sprintf('views_view__%s', $view->id());
  // Add a more specific template suggestion for the list display.
  $suggestions[] = sprintf('views_view__%s__%s', $view->id(), $view->getDisplay()->display['id']);
}


function starter_d9_2022_theme_suggestions_views_view_list_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $suggestions[] = sprintf('views_view_list__%s', $view->id());
  // Add a more specific template suggestion for the list display.
  $suggestions[] = sprintf('views_view_list__%s__%s', $view->id(), $view->getDisplay()->display['id']);
}
```

The template suggestion will follow the pattern views-view--<view_id>--<display_id>.html.twig and views-view-list--<view_id>--<display_id>.html.twig as example.

Don't forget to clear the Drupal cache after making these changes so that the new template suggestions can take effect.

I hope this helps!